# The Server block is not well formed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to add aspx view in MVC instead of Razor View.

I'm getting error at line `<%@ Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>`

Parser Error Message: The server block is not well formed. <--- In browser

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="List.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Views.EmployeesPart25MVC.List" %> <%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1" %> <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head runat="server">
          <title></title>    </head>    <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
             <div>
                <h2>
                   Gomathi
                </h2>
                <table class="table">
                   <tr>
                      <th>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender) %>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City) %>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentsPart25MVC.Name) %>
                      </th>
                      <th></th>
                   </tr>
                   <%@foreach (var item in Model) 
                      { %>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender) %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City) %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                         <%@ Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentsPart25MVC.Name) %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                         <%@ Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
                            Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
                            Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmployeeID })  %>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <%@ } %>
                </table>
             </div>
          </form>    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In aspx engine `<%@ %>` is only used for page directives, and cannot be used elsewhere.

For all the HTML output you would normally use `<%= %>`:

```
<%= Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>
```

and for code blocks just `<% %>`:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) 
   { %>
```

Comment: But when i use <%=  %> , Error is showing "The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context" . Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Gom, that's a different problem. You need to sort out your dependencies for the view pages. Quick google search for the error should get you sorted